# Modern page doesn't work with Oslo layout (can't remove sidebar)

Tags: navigation, quick-launch, layouts, oslo

I am using an Oslo layout and I want to get rid of side navigation (quick-launch) bar to utilize more horizontal space. After applying the Oslo layout, sidebar is gone for some pages (classic page, calendar), but it is still there for the others like: modern page, lists, and document library.

Is there any workaround for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no not at the moment, oslo.master page is related to the classic site.

any default master page and/or custom styling will not be reflected on modern pages.

Modern pages and sites/libraries use a different master page that is inherited from a team site only at the moment. When they bring out publishing site then you can update the master page if Microsoft will allows it.

right from the horses mouth:

> These customizations are currently not supported for "modern" pages:+
>
> Adding "classic" web parts on "modern" pages
>
> Custom CSS via AlternateCSSUrl web property
>
> Custom JavaScript embedded via user custom actions (see note on
>   SharePoint Framework Extensions)
>
> **Custom master pages** (more extensive branding will be supported later
>   using alternative options)
>
> Minimal Download Strategy (MDS)

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages

it is best practice to not mix the two. Leads to bad user experience and continuity.

best you can do on a modern site is to switch off the quick launch: 
top left click on the cog icon -> click site settings -> under Look and Feel click on "navigation elements" -> uncheck "Enable Quick Launch" and click ok.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I guess I will stick to Seattle layout for now.

Comment: "it is best practice to not mix the two" - except that's exactly what Microsoft does.

Comment: haha yes the do indeed. its getting better as time goes by and sites become more fully modern.